# Accessing common functions/data from React components

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm new to React and want to understand the right way to handle the following scenario.

Say, I have three React components which are essentially siblings i.e. not nested within each other.

All three components need to know the screen resolution of the user and this resolution may change. For example, the user may set the browser window to a smaller size. Essentially, the view port is in a dynamic state.

I don't want to put the view port detection logic into each component which would produce repetitive code. How do I create a common function that is responsible for view port detection and pass this information to each component?

In the following code sample, I have three components that work independently of each other but they'll all need view port information. What's the right way to handle this?

```
<div id="navigationHere"></div>
<div id="doSomethingHere"></div>
<div id="handleSomethingElseHere"></div>

<script src="nav.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
<script src="doSomething.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
<script src="handleSomethingElse.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

By the way, I'm using this inside an ASP.NET MVC application and thinking about using ReactJs.Net to handle initial state and pre-rendering on the server side. So, it's important for me to understand the right way to handle this within the context of an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Common functions like that should be calculated within the parent and result of the computation passed down as props.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your logic. User can resize the browser window so passing a static value doesn't work. Other option is to use a wrapper/parent component that contains each individual component as well as the function that figures out view port but in that case for every page with a different model, we'd have to create a wrapper component and in that parent/wrapper component we'd still be repeating the function that figures out view port.

Comment: Why pass a static value? In your parent you would attach a listener to the `onResize` event and on each resize event you would pass down the new value for the components or am I totally missing the point?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsbin.com/fofobedumi/edit?js,output - The resize listener could be anything, I just chose that for illustrative purposes.

Comment: This is the second scenario I described where we have a parent component in which we place all the child components as well as the function that detects the view port. In this approach, I'd have to create a parent component for every page AND repeat the function that detects the view port in every parent component as well myProjects parent component that will be used in MyProjects.cshtml, myEmployees parent component which used in MyEmployees.cshtml page. This is what I meant by repetitive code. I'm literally repeating the viewport detection code in every parent component.

Comment: Why? You just need one component and have that placed around your app?

Comment: My app is not a SPA. It's an ASP.NET MVC app. I have different models for each page so each page will have a different set of components. If I were to create a single "app" component, how would I put the components designed for each page e.g. myEmployees component for the MyEmployees page, etc.

Comment: It matters not if you have a SPA or not, you can still create 1 component that you wrap around the other components that you have. Think of it like a class in C# - you can use a class everywhere regardless of what that class does or what it has access to, right?

Comment: I get your point in C# but not sure how to do that in React. If I have an app component and will use that as the parent component for every page, I don't know how to dynamically insert my page specific components into it. Would you be kind enough to give me a code sample?

Comment: `<YourViewPortDetectingComponent><OtherComponent1/><OC2/><OC3/></YourViewPortDetectingComponent>`

Comment: So, you're saying put all the components that I will use on the whole site into my ViewPortComponent?

Comment: If that makes sense to you, then yeah, otherwise just think about composition and you'll figure it out!

Comment: I don't want to load up all my components into a common parent component. That'll only bloat the parent component and most of the child components are not going to be used because any particular page will only need one or two components and the rest are loaded up for no reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97339/discussion-between-limelights-and-sam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for what are known as a higher order components.

First off we define a parent component that keeps track of the screen resolution.

```
var ViewportManager = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return this.measureViewport();
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
  },
  onResize: function() {
    this.setState(this.measureViewport());
  },
  measureViewport: function() {
    return {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    };
  }
});
```

Once this component is mounted it will keep track of the size of the screen, updating each time the browser window is resized. What we need to do now is pass these values down to any components rendered inside of this one.

```
<ViewportManager>
  <NavigationHere />
  <DoSomethingHere />
  <HandleSomethingElseHere />
</Viewport>
```

We'll pass down `viewportHeight` and `viewportHidth` to each of the inner components.

```
var ViewportManager = React.createClass({
  // ...
  render: function() {
    var viewportWidth = this.state.width;
    var viewportHeight = this.state.height;
    var children = this.props.children;
    var additionalProps = {
      viewportWidth: viewportWidth,
      viewportHeight: viewportHeight
    };

    var modifiedChildren = React.Children.map(children, function(child) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, additionalProps);
    });

    return (
      <div className='viewport-manager'>
       {{ modifiedChildren }}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Now all of the components directly inside your `ViewportManager` will receive two additional props.

```
var NavigationHere = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // I can see this.props.viewportWidth
    // and this.props.viewportHeight
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. Also thank you @limelights. I'd like you to get credit for your help. You were super helpful. Not sure I how can give you credit in StackOverflow for all your help.